# SQLAlchemy many-to-many AND filter

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy

I have two models, joined by a many-to-many relationship

```
image_tag = Table('image_tag', Base.metadata,
    Column('image_id', Integer, ForeignKey('images.id')),
    Column('tag_id', Integer, ForeignKey('tags.id'))
)

class Image(Base):
    __tablename__='images'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    tags = relationship('Tag', secondary=image_tag, backref=backref('images', order_by=id.desc()), lazy="joined")

class Tag(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'tags'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    tag = Column(String(64), unique=True)
```

Now lets say I want to filter Images by tag – easy:

```
_tag = "foo"
Image.query.filter(Image.tags.any(tag=_tag)).all()
```

But what if I want to filter by many tags and only want to match those Images which match all of the tags?

```
tags = ["foo", "bar"]
???
```

Any help is incredibly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see two possibilites: Either combine two `EXIST` clauses that check for each element separately or specify a where clause like this:

```
WHERE (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ... WHERE tags.tag in ("foo", "bar")) = 2
```

Both solutions are kinda ugly but I see a problem here more with the way SQL is than with SQLAlchemy.

In both cases I recommend you build a normal SQL query first, test it and them build that in SQLAlchemy equivalently.

By the way, I could imagine both solutions being very inefficient on large sets of data, but I don't see a solution here.

Initially, I would have tried something like `WHERE (SELECT tags.tag FROM ...) = ("foo", "bar")` but that does not seem to be valid SQL (at least MySQL threw an error at me) because the subquery in `WHERE` must return a scalar result.

Comment: You are right, it's more of a SQL problem/misunderstanding on my side than a SQLAlchemy thing. Thank you!